# How to initialize a class and then freeze its argument value

Tags: c++, oop, class, object, initialization

I've a `class String`, which presents a dynamical array of `characters`, which cannot be changed after initialization. So I need to initialize it, and then prevent further changes to the argument.

How can I do this? :)

Comment: Wise-asses call these classes "immutable"

Comment: This kind of unchangeable class is called "immutable"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You make your member `const`. And you do the initialization in the constructor.

```
class String
{
   const char* const _buff;  //both the contents and the pointer are const
public:
   String (const char* buff);
};

String::String(const char* buff) : _buff(buff)
{
}
```

EDIT: As @ildjarn pointed out, take extra care when using immutable objects. You have to be certain that's what you actually need. You won't be able to use them in standard containers, or have logical copying.

Comment: Making data members const is just silly -- it makes your class non-assignable which, among other things, means you can't use instances of your class in C++03 standard containers. A saner solution is to only provide const member functions to access said data members and leave the data members themselves non-const.

Comment: Ok thanks, but how can I create a copy constructor for this class? And a destructor? :)

Comment: @Vidak do you want the member to remain the same or not?

Comment: @ildjarn just because you can't use immutable objects in containers and you can't find a reason to have immutable objects doesn't make them silly.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: immutable objects often make a lot of sense, but you need your language and your library to support them. If you can't use them in standard containers, they're second class citizens. That's not the case in say Scala or functional languages.
Anyway, it does sound like the OP asked for an immutable class which cannot be used in a container. Of course, you can still use containers of pointers to them (as happens, under the hood, in functional languages for most/all values, and as needs to happen for immutable objects).

Comment: @Luchian : My point is that you can make immutable objects without using const data members -- use const member functions instead. I.e., you can have all the benefits without the drawbacks.

Comment: @ildjarn but then you can modify the member from inside the class. He said he doesn't want to change the member after initialization. Initialization only happens once. So you don't have the same benefits. And there are no drawbacks, there are just effects that come from having immutable objects in the first place.

Comment: @Luchian : If your class can't maintain its own invariants in its own implementation then you have far larger problems; your class can still be observably immutable without const data members. Again, not being able to put your objects in standard C++03 containers is a __huge__ drawback and it's irresponsible to not mention that fact to the OP.

Comment: @ildjarn no it's not. If you want to put them in containers, don't make them immutable. It's as simple as that. If you do want them in containers, make them mutable... but it's not what this question is about. Please read it again.

Comment: Recommending anti-patterns and non-idiomatic C++ code just to adhere to the _exact_ request of the OP does not make a good answer, when you could easily recommend something idiomatic that does 99% of the same thing without making the objects useless with the language's own standard library. If you're really oblivious to this fact then I simply don't know what else to say.

Comment: @ildjarn I understand what you're saying. But the question is pretty clear. The op doesn't state a problem and ask for approach suggestions, he's asking how he can achieve a specific thing. I, for one, when I ask a question, hate answers that say "better not do this" and don't answer the question. That's because I know what I should or shouldn't do, but sometimes I just want a straight answer. There are questions and questions. "How do I do **this specific thing**?" versus "How should I approach the problem?"

Comment: That straight answer can include the "this is a bad idea, don't do it" caveat as well. ;-] In any case, I didn't downvote as your code is obviously legitimate; my only contention is that it should be made more clear to the OP that while this code works, it's generally something one would want to avoid.

Comment: @ildjarn I already said I understood what you mean. I edited my answer just in case the op's question isn't for learning purposes.

Comment: Sorry, guess I was over-clarifying my stance. ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn It's all good, I know the feeling. I usually get it when I'm not making myself understood. :)

Answer (score 1):

Set the `innerstring` array as private const, and expose only the `get` method.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>

class String {
public:

  // Default constructor and 
  // conversion constructor
  String(const char *p = "") {
    data_ = new char[strlen(p)+1];
    strcpy(data_, p);
  }


  // copy constructor
  String(const String& rhs) {
    data_ = new char[strlen(rhs.data_)+1];
    strcpy(data_, rhs.data_);
  }

  ~String() {
    delete[] data_;
  }

  String& operator=(const String&rhs) {
    String temp(rhs);
    std::swap(temp.data_, data_);
    return *this;
  }

  // operator[] is the only data access, and it returns "const&"
  const char&operator[](std::size_t i) { return data_[i]; }

private:
  char *data_;
};



int main () {
  String a("Hello");
  String b("Goodbye");
  std::vector<String> v;

  v.push_back("a");
  v.push_back("b");
  v.push_back(&b[4]);

  b = a;

  std::cout << &b[0] << "\n";
  std::cout << &v[2][0] << "\n";
}
```